# Ampersand being sent as &amp;amp; rather than &amp; when attempting to update MySQL database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am currently building an "admin" section where the information shown on the main site can be added to, updated and deleted using this one page.

All of my scripts function as intended, information is added to the database, rows are updated and deleted with no errors in 99.9% of cases.

The database is set up with 3 columns TITLE, DESCRIPTION and Image and when updating any of the rows I use the value in TITLE as my reference for WHERE statements.

However, any title containing an '&' symbol are downloaded fine and insert into my HTML as intended, however when being sent to my update script they are sent as &amp;. This then doesn't register correctly with the update script and then it fails to update. I know '&' is converted to '&' when escaped but cannot understand why there is a second 'amp;' being sent?

Can anyone shed some light on this / point me to appropriate documentation to solve this issue?

Javscript Function(dbtable and titler are variables that decide the table to insert into )

```
    function updating(indexno) {
                var current = document.getElementById('title'+indexno).innerHTML;
                var newtitle = document.getElementById('titlelink'+indexno).value;
                var newdesc = document.getElementById('desclink'+indexno).value;
                var newimage = document.getElementById('imagelink'+indexno).value;
                if(newtitle == ""){
                    newtitle = document.getElementById('title'+indexno).innerHTML;
                };
                if(newdesc == ""){
                    newdesc = document.getElementById('description'+indexno).innerHTML;
                };
                if(newimage == ""){
                    newimage = document.getElementById('image'+indexno).innerHTML;
                }
                var request = "updatingdb.php?newtitle="+escape(newtitle)+"&newdesc="+escape(newdesc)+"&newimage="+escape(newimage)+"&currenttitle="+escape(current)+"&thetable="+escape(dbtable);
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("GET", request);
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                        console.log(xhr.responseText);

                    }
                };
                xhr.send(null);
                thetester(dbtable,titler);
    }
```

PHP Script

```
    $thetable = htmlentities($_GET['thetable']);
            $currenttitle = htmlentities($_GET['currenttitle']);
            $newtitle = htmlentities($_GET['newtitle']);
            $newdesc = htmlentities($_GET['newdesc']);
            $newimage = htmlentities($_GET['newimage']);

            $db = mysqli_connect($servername, $user, $password);

            if (!$db)
                {
                    echo"NO CONNECTION AVAILABLE";
                    exit();
                }

            mysqli_select_db ($db, "testing");

            $query ="UPDATE `$thetable` SET `TITLE`= '$newtitle', `DESCRIPTION` ='$newdesc', `IMAGE` = '$newimage' WHERE `TITLE` = '$currenttitle'";

            echo$query;

            $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);


            if(!$results)
                {
                    echo"not working";
                    exit();
                }

            echo"updated";
```

Comment: `htmlentities` is not the correct function to prepare data for insertion into an SQL query to begin with. Data should be treated appropriate _for_ the context you are bringing it into, _when_ you are bringing it into that context. And `escape` in JS is deprecated, and also not really the correct function to use here either.

Comment: @04FS Can you elaborate further? As the sum of your comment when boiled down was "you're wrong" with no guidance as to what to use/ where to go to find the relevant information that will help to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you use `htmlentities()`, which will just see the `&` character and therefore makes an entity out of it. You could either remove `htmlentities` from the desired input field or do something like this:

```
$value = str_replace('&amp;amp;', '&amp;', htmlentities($value));
```

or (better imo)

```
$value = htmlentities(html_entity_decode($value));
```

Comment: This has actually added an addition 'amp;' to the value. 

So using A&B comes up as A*amp;amp;B